# SQL Server - Return different values based on row count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, table 1 is the target table, I’ve provided the required values in idCode1- idCode3.

Table 2 is the source, each idBill will have one or more idCode. If there were two rows to represent 2 unique idCode, then I want to insert to idCode 1 and 2 respectively.

I was thinking a case statement where I could test for the number of idCode and then insert first value to 1, second value to 2 etc. When I tried a bunch of case, when, exists, count etc it would always return 2 rows if there were 2 idCode values, and the idCode would only insert to idCode1. The end result must be a single row in table1 for each idBill and however many idCode for that idBill inserted to 1, 2, 3.

Sorry I couldn’t post the picture as I don’t have enough points. Here is a rough pipe delimited example of it:

```
| idTable1 | idBill | idCode1 | idCode2 | idCode3 |
| 1        | 1234   | A1      | A2      |         | 
| 2        | 1235   | E3      | E2      | A1      |

| idTable2 | idBill | codeId |
| 10       | 1234   | A1     |
| 20       | 1234   | A2     |
| 30       | 1235   | E3     |
| 40       | 1235   | E2     |
| 50       | 1235   | A1     |
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: data as text is prefered here over pictures, so we are glad you did it like this

Comment: Please post you best (so far) attempt of a query. Add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select s.idbill,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then s.codeid end) as codeid1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then s.codeid end) as codeid2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then s.codeid end) as codeid3
into target
from (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by idbill order by idtable2) as seqnum
      from source s
     ) s
group by s.idbill;
```